# Renaming files in ksh script

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file namely:

> xpress_railway_20140519.xml

Now I need to insert a unique id into the output file name. For example, my output now should be:

> xpress_railway_1000(unique id)_20140519.xml

How should I do this is ksh shell scripting? This unique id is present in one file called `xpress_uni_fcdm.parm` which is a parameter file and the unique id is present in 5th line inside this file. I tried `awk` and `grep` but I'm not sure with my output. Can you please help?

Comment: I don't understand. You have a single filename that you want to change? Just rename it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Or `tail -n +5 | head -n 1` :-)

Comment: @ooga: Why two commands when one will do? `sed -n 5p` does what is needed; so does `sed -e 1,4d -e 5q`.

Comment: Do you need to update the parameter file with a new value (the old unique ID plus one, for example)?  Do you mean that the output file name is `xpress_railway_1000_20140519.xml` or do the words `(unique id)` really appear in the file name?  Is the `xpress_railway` part of the name fixed?  Presumably, the date portion of the name is arbitrary.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I suppose that second `sed` example is the most efficient. I'm surprised that `head` doesn't have a way to skip a given number of lines before printing a given number.

Comment: @ooga: yes, the second `sed` is more efficient because it stops processing at the fifth line.  OTOH, some programs (not many) get upset and print warnings if the child to which they are writing dies early; for those, the first is a better choice (it avoids a pointless warning).  Here, the second is better (and could be compressed to `sed '1,4d;5q'` if you prefer compactness over readability).

Comment: i have the unique id in xpress_uni_fcdm.parm i have to take that from the file and append it to the output.

Comment: ooga I'm surprised that `head` even exists, given that `sed` provides all of the necessary functionality!

Comment: hi friends i have got the unique id and moved into the file unique id .txt..this is present in one path.now i have to rename it from xpress_railway_20140519.xml to xpress_railway_1000(unique id)_20140519.xml.how to take that unique id from that path and append ..please help me at earliest.

Answer (score 0):

The following works with ksh and any POSIX sh for that matter...

```
OLD=xpress_railway_20140519.xml
UID=$(awk 'NR == 5 { print; exit 0 }' xpress_uni_fcdm.parm)
NEW=$(printf '%s' "$OLD" | sed -e "s/_[[:digit:]]\+.xml$/_${UID}&/")
mv "$OLD" "$NEW"
```

You could use head -n5 | tail -n1 for the UID, but I think that you will find the AWK statement to be more efficient then a pipeline of two commands; and, actually, it just looks clearer as to intent. (Using SED would be OK too, but more cryptic -- also, the AWK statement can be most easily extended to filter out any detritus.)

Tested with:

```
$ ksh --version
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01
```